# How to setup local chef server to authenticate with SSO

Tags: chef-infra

We have our own Chef server. Today we create users locally through Chef UI but want to integrate SSO with chef so we can login using our SSO id's rather than creating local users in chef, Is this possible today ? If yes can you point me to the documentation or setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only "SSO" (it's not actually SSO, but external auth sources) that Chef Server/Manage support are LDAP and Active Directory. You can find the docs at https://docs.chef.io/server_ldap.html.

Comment: thanks looks like this feature is only available for version 12+. I am actually running 11

Comment: That is correct, LDAP integration is not available for the Open Source 11.x server.